# How does the predict function in statmodels work for a single future value?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to understand simple regression and how the model predict work. The result of predict is an array of fitted values.
But what if I only want one value for example.

If I want X=11 ( expected predict to only give me 110 ) why do I still get array of output and how can I reduce to only one value ? to get 110 ?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
X = sm.add_constant(X)                          
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()
ypred = model.predict(11)
print(ypred)
```

Output :

```
[[  11.   11.]
 [  11.   22.]
 [  11.   33.]
 [  11.   44.]
 [  11.   55.]
 [  11.   66.]
 [  11.   77.]
 [  11.   88.]
 [  11.   99.]
 [  11.  110.]]
```

Comment: You need to use `results.predict([1, 11])` not model.predict. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714057/what-is-first-value-that-is-passed-into-statsmodels-predict-function for why you need the extra `1`